# SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 Pulishing Queue Deleted Possible to Roll back or get the information in the Database

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1

One of our client today. looking for some information regarding the SDL Tridion 2013 Publishing queue was deleted by some one.

Is is possible to rollback the publishing queue or get to know from any other table these deleted items information.

There is one DCP component has been published to live and also publishing queue has been deleted by some one. Client may want to know who is published that article to live and who is deleted that component from publishing queue.

Please advise how to get these information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The publish queue it essentially a list of so-called Publish Transactions and a Publish Transaction has a Creator property representing the person who performed the (un-)publish action.
However, if the Publish Transaction is deleted, there won't be a trace of who that was, nor who deleted it; there is no OOTB audit trail functionality in the system (that would be easy to implement as event handlers going forward, BTW).

Answer (score 2):

I got the information from who is published that article information from `PUBLISH_STATES` table on CMS DATABASE

```
SELET [PUBLICATION_TARGET_ID],[TRUSTEE_ID] FROM [Tridion_cm].[dbo].[PUBLISH_STATES] where REFERENCE_ID = 11002
```

I know once the publishing queue deleted items we can't retrieve, it's deleted from table.

Comment: You really shouldn't try and find stuff yourself in the database, it is not an open data model. Any information you need to get from the CMS, you should get via the public APIs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to retrieve the deleted transaction information once the item is is republished or the transaction is removed explicitly as far as I know.

A way to avoid this issue is to capture the information while the transaction is being processed for publishing. The package which is generated after rendering contains the xml (pages.xml for pages or component_presentations.xml for DCPs) files which contains the details for publish transaction tcm id, the asset (page/DCP) getting published, its tcm id and the version of the item being published. You can capture it and store it (in custom db). And you can write a GUI extension to present the publish information for any selected item by taking in the tcm id as an input for the GUI and fetching the details from your custom captured information which will give full details of who published, when it was published and what version of the item was published.

We have implemented the same and it is really useful since Tridion OOTB does not keeps publish transaction details and overrides as soon as the same item is republished and it does not captures version of the item getting published.